# Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

```
2013-01-18 02:42:11,487|INFO||GatewayOutboundPollerDaemon|Begin pollGatewayIncident().
2013-01-18 02:42:32,225|INFO||GatewayOutboundPollerDbHelper|Begin submitPendingRecords().
2013-01-18 02:42:54,565|INFO||GatewayOutboundPollerDbHelper|Query for Pending Records : SELECT TR_GATEWAY_RECORD_ID, decode(TR_TRANSACTION_TY
PE,1,'Update','Create')TR_TRANSACTION_TYPE, TR_GATEWAY_RECORD_STATUS FROM TM4530_INCIDENT_GATEWAY WHERE TR_GATEWAY_RECORD_STATUS = 0 AND TR_F
ROM_PARTNER = 'RAM' AND TR_GATEWAY_RECORD_STATE = 0 AND TR_TRANSACTION_METHOD = 1 FOR UPDATE
2013-01-18 02:49:47,527|ERROR||DaemonExecutor|ExecutableDaemon threw an exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

my memory size increasing slowly and after 1 month or 2month  I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. If I restart my server The problem has resolved.

Can u please suggest to me how to resolve this problem permanently?

Comment: You probably have some memory leaks...

Answer (score 1):

Since you've not specified your environment and what JDK you are using and the configuration settings you're using when running your application (e.g., memory usage), I suggest to increase your heap size using the `-Xmx` mnemonic.

E.g.

```
java -Xmx6g MyProgram
```

where `6g` means that I want 6GB heap size (on a 64-bit environment).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a memory profiler to detect why memory is increasing.
I resolved that kind of problem using Java VisualVM